# Using ARM NEON is slower in a simple Addition task

Tags: arm, neon

I tried to compose a simple piece of NEON code but found it is slower than regular C++ implementation. The code is as below

```
float A[] = {1,2,3,4}; 
float B[] = {2,3,4,5}; 
float32x4_t v1;
float32x4_t v2;

int counter = 1000000;

while(counter--){
     v1 = vld1q_f32(A);
     v2 = vld1q_f32(B);
     v = vaddq_f32(v1,v2);

     vst1q_f32(A,v);
     // A[0] = A[0]+B[0]; // regular implementation
     // A[1] = A[1]+B[1]; // regular implementation 
     // A[2] = A[2]+B[2]; // regular implementation
     // A[3] = A[3]+B[3]; // regular implementation

 }
```

I searched for the reason so I guess it is because of the in-order pipeline and this simple task cause stall in CPU? But could anyone help explain more in detail? And is there any way to improve the performance of this NEON implementation? Or is it better to use the regular implementation than using NEON when facing this kind of simple task? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test routine is completely flawed to start with:

Since all the inputs are clearly visible to the compiler at build time, the compiler will simply generate machine codes similar to the one below:

```
A[0] = 3.0f;
A[1] = 5.0f;
A[2] = 7.0f;
A[3] = 9.0f;
```

In order to prevent compilers from this kind of cheating, you have to hide the inputs:

```
void myFunc_c(float *pA, float *pB, uint32_t count)
{
    if (count == 0) return;

    do {
        *pA++ += *pB++;
    } while (--count);
}

void myFunc_neon(float *pA, float *pB, uint32_t count)
{
    float32x4_t a, b;

    count >>= 2;
    if (count == 0) return;

    do {
        a = vld1q_f32(pA);
        b = vld1q_f32(pB);

        a = vaddq_f32(a, b);

        vst1q_f32(pA, a);

        pA += 4;
        pB += 4;

    } while (--count);    
}
```

All you need to do is to allocate enough memory for `pA` and `pB`, initialize them if you want, and call the functions above.

I think the neon version will be roughly 3 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you use intrinsics for load/store the compiler seems to leave them alone.

Without intrinsics it can optimize away the load/store and use just registers for intermediate values. Have a look at the generated assembly: https://www.godbolt.org/z/FvqKP3

In addition, I would guess loading something into NEON while the same memory is just being written by another transfer could be a such a rare use-case that the CPU designers wouldn't have bothered to implement a direct bypass. You may have to wait until the store is fully finished before the load can start.